# How to pre-fill the file name in a QFileDialog?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qfiledialog

Good day,

I made a program to take measurements and plot them on a graph. The user can then export the data as .csv or the graph as .png at a custom location with a custom name thanks to QFileDialog. Below is the code, anyone feel free to use it for yourself.

My question is: **how to pre-fill the file name in the dialog box** so that the user can still specify a custom name, but if they don't care it's already filled with experimental parameters. Thanks in advance.

```
def export_picture(self):
    """Grabs the plot on the interface and saves it in a .png file at a custom location."""

    # Setup a file dialog.
    MyDialog = QFileDialog()
    MyDialog.setWindowTitle("Select a location to save your graph.")
    MyDialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
#   MyDialog.a_method_to_prefill_the_file_name("name") <-- ?
    MyDialog.exec_()

    # Abort the function if somebody closed the file dialog without selecting anything.
    if len(MyDialog.selectedFiles()) == 0:
        return

    # Save the file and notify the user.
    CompleteName = MyDialog.selectedFiles()[0] + ".png"
    self.ui.Graph.figure.savefig(fname=CompleteName, dpi=254, format="png")
    Directory, File = os.path.split(FileAndPath)
    print('Graph exported as "%s.png" in the folder "%s".' %(File, Directory))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getSaveFileName.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Get File Name...')
    button.show()

    def _get_file_name():
        save_file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(button, "Save File...", 'foo.txt')
        print(f'save_file = {save_file}')

    button.clicked.connect(_get_file_name)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow and come back to you.

Comment: Not a big fan of having all the arguments implicit, as opposed to using methods like `.setWindowTitle()` for example, but it works. Can I ask why the comma after the name of the variable?

Comment: It returns a 2-tuple.  The second element is the file type selection, ie, "Img (*.jpg, *.png)". If you are not interested in that element, you can assign it to the don't care variable.  I could have just as well used save_file, file_mask = ..., but then there'd have an unused variable.

Comment: If anyone from the future stumbles upon this: `file_dialog.selectFile("pre-filled text goes here")` works very well, with `file_dialog` being a `QFileDialog` you created beforehand.